# Pass variable from aspx.vp to node.js(client side)

Tags: node.js, vb.net

I want to pass variable which is fetch from .ini file in aspx.vb file and want to pass this to node.js file is that possible?
Or If I got how to read flag value from .ini it self in node js file only. Anyone approch will be helpful

Thanks, your help will be helpful to me.